# Equivalence of static const char* in a java function

Tags: java, c++

I make regular use of this idiom in C++:

```
/*return type*/ foo(/*parameters*/){
    static const char* bar = "Bar";
    /*some code here*/
}
```

Internally this gets added to a table of string literals. Does this Java code do a similar thing:

```
/*return type*/ foo(/*parameters*/){
    final String bar = "Bar";
    /*some code here*/
}
```

or am I unwittingly introducing inefficiencies here?

Comment: function static variable might not be as efficient as you might think, it is possible that the generated code is checking whether it is initialized every time you call the function. Although in this case it will probably be optimized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strings are immutable in Java. This means you don't have to give hints to have the JVM know it won't change and optimize it.

String literals are interned to avoid redundancies, which means they already are "added to a table of string literals". Using `final` here isn't necessary.

Comment: Not quite. `final` prevents the String *reference* from being modified to point to a different string, so if you want a truly constant string, it should be `final`.

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution is correct and they are as near to equivalent as Java can express.

As other answers have mentioned strings are immutable and the final does not add any performance enhancement, however I feel the final is semantically useful here. Much like 'const' in c++; 'final' ensures that the value cannot be changed and attempting to do so will result in a compiler error - it seems to me that this is a desirable behavior in your case.

Also (much as in the case with c++ const) it might lead to some possible optimizations that otherwise would not be considered.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify for a string to be added to the literal pool (referred to as interning in Java) by invoking `String.intern()` as follows:

```
final String bar = myString.intern();
```

It is basically the same concept as the literal pool, using the same object for the given string. Note that string literals are interned automatically. It also allows you to compare interned strings by reference, so it *might* be more efficient. However, you must always compare the strings returned via `intern()`. Thus

```
a.equals(b);
```

could be replaced with

```
a.intern() == b.intern();
```

Note that you don't actually want to the above exactly as depicted. Ideally you can keep the interned strings around and reuse them. However, there are some pitfalls to interned strings. They are not garbage collected, and the the method itself is a bit expensive.

Comment: Using `intern()` on a string literal is just useless!

Comment: @GyroGearless Yes, I know. I need a better example.

Answer (score 0):

The `final` keyword in a Java method doesn't do what you think it does.

In this particular case, `final` makes the variable unmodifiable. That's it. The content itself does get added to a global table of String constants, but the pointer to it (pardon the terminology) is technically set every single time.

The `final` keyword is mainly useful from within a method to make the variable available to any anonymous classes you create after it. It's Java's piss-poor half-assed support for what they like to consider "closure". And it also happens to be the *only* way you can access an outer variable from within an inner anonymous class.

```
final String bar = "Bar";
final Set<String> allTheBars = new HashSet<>() {{
    add(bar);
}};
```

Comment: It is better for you (and the JIT) if a closure cannot modify your state. Hence, I wouldn't call it "piss-poor".

Comment: @Ingo fair enough, perhaps "inconsistent" then. You can modify the outer-most class's variables with no problem (using ClassName.this.varName) and yet you can't do anything to the nearby ones.

Comment: -1 final is a important part of the java language useful in many context for many different things (sealing classes, ensuring constants remain constant, allowing closure over local variables etc) your emotive criticism of the construct does little to help or inform the asker.

Comment: @Chris Even worse, you can modify state through a `final` reference, like in `final int[] foo = new int[] {42}; new Runnable() { void run() { foo[0] = 43; }}`

Comment: @Elemental did I say anything about it being unimportant? The first paragraph explains the usage, the second explains *in the original context* why the final keyword isn't terribly useful for the OP (again, IN THE ORIGINAL CONTEXT). I called it piss-poor because it's piss poor IN THIS CONTEXT. I wasn't being emotional, I was simply informing the OP that other languages have far better facilities than Java offers. In. This. Context.

Comment: @Ingo That's a hack. While I agree that it will accomplish what you're after, you're essentially bypassing the very same immutability that you claimed was important in your first comment.

Comment: @Chris Indeed it is a hack. I am not suggesting to do that, but remember how easy it is to do it without wanting it by accident via `finalReference.unsuspiciousMethod(bla,blubb)` where `unsuspiciousMethod` changes the state referenced by `finalReference`. This is a really, really bad thing in Java.

Comment: @Ingo I think you missed the point here. In Java, declaring something `final` is the *only* way to expose it to an enclosed anonymous class. I agree, modifying final is a Bad Thing (tm). But there's no way to pass it a non-final, and **that** is the shortcoming. It's immutable or nothing, which leads to clever hacks like what you just showed, rather than cleaner syntax that you see in most other languages.

Comment: @Chris "immutable or nothing" if only it were so! But apparently, "immutable" was not something the Java inventors had in their vocabulary ... but we disgress.